# Which aircraft is a single-prop, low-wing aircraft with prominent rivets and three canopy windows?

Tags: aircraft-identification

We would appreciate help identifying an aircraft that my daughter saw. It is a single-prop, low-wing design with a round fuselage and very prominent rivets.

It had a prominent canopy that stood above the fuselage with visible windows, and the rudder was visibly slated as well.

[image]

Comment: The very mention of 'prominent rivets' makes me immediately think of Douglas aircraft, such as the SBD Dauntless.

Comment: Why the downvotes? There are many [aircraft identification](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft-identification) question on this site, the question is even tagged for it!

Comment: Can you tell us where you saw it? And does your daughter remember anything about the color or markings?

Comment: @Pondlife She just sent to me the drawing. I don't know if she saw it on the ground or in the air. I'll ask tomorrow when I see her if we don't have a good candidate by then. Thanks!

Comment: The existence of a canopy would seem to indicate a military plane. Were the windows on the canopy actually that small and square (or at least squarish?) Does the tailfin actually have a rudder that sits entirely above the tailplane but doesn't extend to the top of the fin? These details would really narrow it down since such configurations are relatively uncommon.

Comment: This seems hopeless. The detail level of the drawing is just "OK, it's a low-winged single-seat prop plane with rivetted construction." It could be anything.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: You underestimate the Aviation.SE community as a resource. Mike Sowsun answered the question perfectly below!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I saw your daughter’s drawing I thought of the Vultee P-66 “Vanguard”.

[image]
[image]

But the Republic P-47 “Thunderbolt” might also be a good candidate.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'll show her this post and we'll answer together.

Comment: P-47 it was. She saw a drawing of one in class. **Thank you!**

Comment: I am amazed at this result :D